# Store multiple Objects from .getJson multiple .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each, var

I've ran into an issue where I need to grab and store all three "house" and "exposure" from the JSON file based on if the URL has ID-1 or ID-2 etc.. I have them in a .each loop where it correctly iterates through the .JSON Listening for correct parameters passed in the URL. 
So for example. http://localhost/?houseblock=ID-1 will now only load the JSON inside of ID-1. But I need to fetch and store for later use all three "house" and "exposure" numbers.

I'm a bit unfamiliar on how to do this correctly, I thought telling the .each to stop after one loop to grab the "house" and "exposure" and then on second loop do it again for the secondary "house" and "exposure". But that doesn't seem to be the case.

**JSON jsonFile.json**

```
{
   "ID-1":{
      "1-1":{
         "house":6,
         "exposure":1
      },
      "1-2":{
         "house":1,
         "exposure":3
      },
      "1-3":{
         "house":3,
         "exposure":2
      }
   },
   "ID-2":{
      "2-1":{
         "house":3,
         "exposure":2
      },
      "2-2":{
         "house":6,
         "exposure":5
      },
      "2-3":{
         "house":1,
         "exposure":1
      }
   }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // -- Listen to URL Changes --//
    var urlListen;
    (window.onpopstate = function()
    {
        var match,
            pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function(s)
            {
                return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, "-"));
            },
            query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        urlListen = {};
        while (match = search.exec(query)) urlListen[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
    var retrieveAll = $.getJSON('jsonFile.json', function(data) {}).done(function(data)
    {
        $(data[urlListen["houseblock"]]).each(function(i, val)
        {
            $.each(val, function(j, b)
            {
                $.each(b, function(k, v)
                {
                    console.log(k + " : " + v);
                    if (k == "house")
                    {
                        houseObj = v;
                        houseObj2 = v;
                        houseObj3 = v;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }).fail(function(data)
    {
        console.log("error");
    }).always(function(data)
    {
        console.log("complete");
    });
    retrieveAll.complete(function(data)
    {
        init();
    });
});

function init()
{
    console.log(houseObj);
    console.log(houseObj2);
    console.log(houseObj3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but the following snippet stores all the `house` and `exposure` values into their own arrays. You need not use `$.each`; it's simpler to use Javascript's native `map`.

From the code you posted I am assuming you can abstract out components of your logic into a function `getCurrentHouseBlockID` (or something similar).

```
var id = getCurrentHouseBlockID();  // 'ID-1'
var dataForID = Object.keys(jsonData[id]);  // ['1-1', '1-2', '1-3']
var houseNums = dataForID.map(function getHouseNum(key) {
    return dataForID[key].house;
});
var exposureNums = dataForID.map(function getExposureNum(key) {
    return dataForID[key].exposure;
});
```